# Phrases about art

Tags: expressions

May I ask if the following phrases, which talk about art, sound natural?

1. The concept/ notion of one's art creations 
   (To describe the rationale behind an artist's work)

---

2. America's art
3. America's art creations
   (To describe artworks made in America/ made by American artists)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We do not ordinarily speak of the things created by artists as *creations* but as *works*

> the works of Shakespeare/Mozart/Picasso
>   works by Shakespeare/Mozart/Picasso

And we rarely qualify these as *art works* or *artistic works* except in contexts where we must distinguish works in different media (here *art* generally signifies works in graphic or plastic visual media) or distinguish works in artistic media from works in other fields:

> contemporary paintings and artworks by Stefano Gentile
>   the political, philosophical and artistic works of Voltaire

In speaking of a set of art works we may speak of the (countable) *works* or (uncountable) *work* of an individual or school; uncountable *art*, when it does not signify artistic value or artistic technique, is used for more general sets, such as *20th century art* or *American art*, and it ordinarily refers only to work in the visual media.